# get class name from group of links in ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

hey guys, i've been pulling my hair out over this one. I need to get the class name of each link in an unordered list. I know it sounds easy enough, but it's a little more complicated than

`$('ul > li > a').attr('class');`

I have a pretty large menu of all the departments in our company. there are something like 33-34 items in the list. Each department except 3 or so has a sub department, and many of the items in each sub department have a sub department. Now I'm the only programmer here and my bosses wanted a solution where a non-programmer could add/remove items from the menu. Due to limitations with the ecommerece platform we use (easystore creator, and no i wouldn't recommend it to anyone) I can't use a database or any server side languages. So I'm using a XML file that contains all the departments, sub departments and level three departments. I then use the `$.ajax()` method to load the xml file and parse the XML data into the menu.

I'm good until I get to the part where I have to build the level three menus. I have an array that contains true/false as to if the given submenu has a level three menu in it somewhere. The position of the bool in the array plus 1 corresponds with the submenu. So if `flag[0] = false` it means that submenu1 has no level three menu.

I went ahead and appended an unordered list with the class `level3` to each item in the submenu if it has a level three menu in it somewhere. In the XML file the node that contains the level three information is called `<levelThreeItem>` and has an attribute `for` that tells which item in the submenu the level three menu goes to. The `for` attribute is formatted `deptXX.YY` where XX is the submenu it belongs to and YY is the item in the submenu it belongs to. So if it where `dept05.02` it means that submenu 05, item 02 (items start counting at 00).

This is wear the class comes in. Each link in the first sub menu, or levelTwo as I call it, has a class `levelTwoLinkXX` where XX is the order of the links. Ex. if there are 4 links in the submenu the first link is `levelTwoLink00` and the last is `leveTwoLink03`. Now what I am trying to do is fill an array with the classes of the levelTwo menu only if it has a level three menu. So far the only thing i've managed to accomplish is load all the classes for each link from every levelTwo menu into the array.

I hope I've explained everything. If there is anything I need to clear up, please let me know; and thanks in advance

Edit:
html structure:

```
<div id="leftNav">
    <ul class="level1">
        <li><a href="#">Dept 1</a>
            <ul class="level2">
                <li class="deptName"><a href="#">Dept 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="levelTwoLink00">Dept1.1</a>
                    <ul class="level3"></ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="levelTwoLink01">Dept1.2</a>
                    <ul class="level3"></ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Suppose levelTwoLink01 has a level three menu and levelTwoLink00 does not. I need to remove the level3 ul from that list item

Comment: Did you know that HTML is an XML derivative, just have a separate HTML file instead of a complicated XML file, and then load that with the `jQuery.get()`.

Comment: Would love to see how the HTML `<ul>..<ul>` is structured.

Comment: @Marcus, yes i am aware, but given that someone with little to no knowledge of html will be maintaining the list i feel that xml is a better solution since i can define the nodes with names that make sense for a menu, rather than a bunch of `<ul>` and `<li>` tags

Comment: @heymrcarter So are your company employees not editing this XML?

Comment: I'm with Marcus on this one - In my experience, giving someone who doesn't know what he's doing an HTML file to make simple edits to is MUCH safer than giving them an XML file to make simple edits to. The more you parse automatically, the more a small mistake can make everything explode... As long as your HTML is clearly indented and he can copy/paste from another part of it and change the appropriate values, that's probably going to be the easiest way for both you AND him.

Comment: @Marcus Yes they would be editing the XML

Comment: @Mala Well it certainly would be easier for me. i guess if i left really thorough comments in the html it'd be manageable

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this...

```
var level2sWithLevel3s = [];
$('.level3').each(function() {
    level2sWithLevel3s.push($(this).prev().attr('class'));
});
```